# Videos on YouTube and Windows Media Player are oversaturated; have too much contrast

Tags: video, windows-media-player, display-settings, contrast

When I play videos on Youtube in minimum screen or middle-sized, videos are normal.  However when I play them in fullscreen the video is oversaturated (has too much contrast and light).

The same happens on any video online, not just YouTube.

It also happens when I play any video with Windows Media Player at any size. When I play movies with other players like MPC and VLC, its fine. I think some settings for online playing and Media Player are screwed up.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Operating system? Did you install additional codecs or something?

Comment: ^ a ffshow filter could do that, or your video cards software, so what video card is it?  For AMD there are 2 different color adjustments one for "desktop" which is all the 2d stuff, and one for the 3D which is anything rendered 3D style including videos.

Comment: May be worth adding more information regarding your setup. What OS and hardware are you running?  Have you updated or installed anything recently related to the graphics or video playback?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adjusting the settings in my graphic card.

The option for making better picture was on. I reverted it to the original settings.